# OTA problem iphone

Tags: iphone

MIME type OTA(Over the AIR) for iphone....

I have created simple application in iphone 3.0.
I want to upload my exe(file) in local webservice.
Now i want to download this from that site and install in iphone ....

How can i did this ?

Is it possible ?

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance..............

Answer (score 1):

First, NO iPhone will run an EXE file.

Second, NO iphone will allow an "install" like a computer would.  You can bring files into your app, and your app can do what it likes with them, but you will not be able to install an entire app this way.

Third, to answer your question, you can use

```
+[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:]
```

to get the file from your server into the phone, then use this data to write to file, or do whatever you will.

Answer (score 0):

You use Xcode to install your app.  Not a webservice.  Why are you uploading and downloading?

Brings me back to the question I asked you in your last (duplicate) [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448043).

Answer (score 0):

If you've switched to using iOS 4 since this post was created, you can distribute your apps wirelessly to devices. See the "Installing Apps Wirelessly" section of this document:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/FA_Wireless_Enterprise_App_Distribution/Introduction/Introduction.html